# Installing homebrew -> grunt error associated with .rvm/ruby

Tags: macos, rvm, gruntjs, homebrew, macports

I apologize if this is an overly specific, I would just like to move up in the world of package management, but at the same time I don't want to overload rebuilding my current dependencies.

So, I tried installing homebrew, but of course I had at some point installed macports, though I don't remember it. Easily enough I just moved it for now by running `sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports`. The problem is, now when I run grunt I get the following error:

```
/Users/KBD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require': dlopen(/Users/KBD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/digest/sha1.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError) Referenced from: /Users/KBD/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin12.4.0/digest/sha1.bundle
```

This obviously has to do with me moving the /opt/lib, but my question is whether or not in order to make this transition I need to completely re-install ruby/.rvm under brew, and re-install all of my gems. This seems tedious and I would rather not go this route, but I don't really know the best way to solve this.

I've found plenty of write-ups around this general subject (macports -> brew) through searches, but nothing specific to this, or maybe it's that everything was too specific to something else. Since I don't even remember using macports, I don't really have any idea what I installed with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the complete reinstall option, especially if you're using `grunt-contrib-sass` or `grunt-contrib-compass`. Temporarily restore your gems and then you can do `gem list` at the prompt to get a list of all of them. Save that somewhere and then follow the guide at http://rvm.io/ - that's what I did (or you can use brew). Gem management is much easier under RVM, you may as well bite the bullet now and get it over with.